# How to call a controller function from a service?

Tags: angularjs, controller, angular-services

i have 2 controllers who are not in the same scope or have a parent child relation.

So i want to call from controlleB a function in ControllerA. In my case its a listContoller with an addItem function and i want to call this function from a addItemController somewhere else on the page after clicking submit. i know this should work with a service, but i dont know how.

```
app.controller("listCtrl", ["$scope", "listSvc", function ($scope, listSvc){
    $scope.list.data = listSvc.load("category");
    $scope.addItem = function(newitem) {
        $scope.list.data.unshift(newitem);
        ...
    }
}]);

app.controller("addItemCrtl", ["$scope", "listSvc", function ($scope, listSvc){
    $scope.addItem = function() {
        listSvc.addItem($scope.newItem);
    }
}]);

app.service('listSvc',  function() {
    return{
        load: function(section){
            ...
        },
        addItem: function(item){
            addItem(item); <<-- call function in listController
        }
    }
});
```

**UPDATE**

k is this better? i put the list.data inside my service and i watch from my controller if the list change and put it on the scope from my controller that ng-repeat can do his work... is this appraoch better? or have someone better tips for me how i should do this...

```
app.service('listSvc',  ['$http', function($http) {
    var list = {};
    return {    
        list:{
            get: function () {
                return list.data;
            },
            set: function (data) {
                list.data = data;
            }           
        },
        addItem: function(item){
            var response = $http.post("/api/album/"+$scope.list.section, item);
            response.success(function(){
                list.data.unshift(item);
                console.log("yeah success added item");
            }).error(function(){
                console.log("buuuh something went wrong");
            });
            return response;
        },

        load: function(section){
            var response = $http.get("/api/album/"+section);
            response.success(function(data){
                list.set(data);
                list.section = section;
                console.log("yeah success loaded list");
            }).error(function(){
                console.log("buuuh something went wrong");
            });
            return response;
        }
    };
}]);
```

and in my controllers i do this

```
app.controller("listCrtl", ["$scope", "listSvc", function ($scope, listSvc){
    listSvc.load("category");
    ...
    $scope.$watch('listSvc.list.get()', function(data) {
        $scope.list.data = data;
    });
    ...
}]);


app.controller("addItemCrtl", ["$scope", "listSvc", function ($scope, listSvc){
    ...
    $scope.addItem = function() {
        listSvc.addItem($scope.newItem);
    }
    ...
}]);
```

gregor ;)

Comment: you can not include $scope inside service. So how can you think about calling a function from service..

Comment: Don't! that's bad design.

Comment: yes thats true :) so how should this problem solved? Should i put all the logic from my controller inside my service ?

Comment: Sure, that's better.  Controller functions are (by design) application-specific.  Services should be business-focused, and application-agnostic. If you can separate out the functionality of your app into services in an application-agnostic way, you should. Then you can inject other dependent services if you need to.

Comment: what do you mean with "application-specific" and "business-focused, and application-agnostic" can you give me a short example? ;)

Comment: i have updated my question with a new approach, maybe you can say me if that is the angular way how i should do this or not ;)

Comment: @GregorOi your answer is missing?

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this myself! Perhaps this may help:

The function inside of my **Controller**:

```
var timeoutMsg = function() {
    vm.$parent.notification = false;
 };
```

The function inside my **Service** (I had to pass in $timeout as well as the name of the function from my **Controller**, now it works):

```
// original broken code:
// this.modalSend = function(vm) {

// fixed:
this.modalSend = function(vm, $timeout, timeoutMsg) {

    vm.$parent.sendTransaction = function() {

        // Show notification
        vm.$parent.message = 'Transaction sent!';
        vm.$parent.notification = true;
        $timeout(timeoutMsg, 4000);

        // original broken code:
        // $timeout(timeoutMsg(), 4000);
    };
}
```

`var vm = $scope`